# Rust Polars .par_iter() for ChunkedArray<Float64Type>?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

In Rust, using Polars, I am writing a custom function to be used within apply/map. This works well:

```
fn capita(x: Series) -> Result<Series> {
    let y = x
            .utf8()
            .unwrap()
            .par_iter() //ParallelIterator
```

However, if my Series was of type f64, then this doesn't work:

```
fn other_fn(x: Series) -> Result<Series> {
    let y = x
            .f64()
            .unwrap()
            .par_iter() // <--- no method par_iter found for reference ChunkedArray<Float64Type>
```

Is there a possible workaround? Looking at utf8.rs I need something like that but for Float64Chunked type.

Many thanks

**EDIT**
I think this workaround has worked, although turned out to be slower, AND giving an unexpected result. using par_bridge:

```
pub fn pa_fa(s: &mut [Series])->Result<Series>{
    let u = s[2].f64()?;
    let n = s[1].f64()?;
    let n_iter = n.into_iter();

    let c: Vec<f64> = n_iter.zip(u).par_bridge().map(
    // ignore this line   let c: Vec<f64> = n_iter.zip(u).map( 
        |(n,u)|{
            n.unwrap().powf(1.777)*u.unwrap().sqrt()
        }
    ).collect();
    Ok(Series::new("Ant", c))
```

Comment: `par_iter` is not yet supported for all `ChunkedArray`s. If you want parallelization you can to slice the arrays in the number of threads and process those in parallel. This gives you far larger units of work per threads.

`polars_core::split_ca` might give some inspiration. Its private so don't depend on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative I found was to collect ChunkedArray into a Vector:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn round_series_float64(series: Series, decimals: u32) -> PolarsResult<Series> {

    let chunkedarray_floatf64 = series
        .f64()?
        .into_iter()
        .collect::<Float64Chunked>();

    let vec_opt_f64: Vec<Option<f64>> = chunkedarray_floatf64
        .into_iter()
        .collect();

    // No sorting required as rayon collects already sorted!

    let new_series: Series = vec_opt_f64
        //.into_iter()
        .into_par_iter() // rayon: parallel iterator
        .map(|opt_f64: Option<f64>|
            opt_f64.map(|float64| round_f64(float64, decimals))
        )
        .collect::<Float64Chunked>()
        .into_series();

    /*
    // No use of rayon:
    let new_series: Series = series
        .f64()?
        .into_iter()
        .map(|opt_f64: Option<f64>|
            opt_f64.map(|float64| round_f64(float64, decimals))
        )
        .collect::<Float64Chunked>()
        .into_series();
    */

    Ok(new_series)
}
```

Such that:

```
pub fn round_f64(value: f64, decimals: u32) -> f64 {
    if decimals == 0 {
        value.round()
    } else {
        let multiplier = 10.0_f64.powf(decimals as f64);
        (value * multiplier).round() / multiplier
    }
}
```